# Adsense ads display issue

Tags: php, javascript, apache, adsense

Ads not appearing in specific 2 pages related to 2 categories ,those categories are holding the latest articles and the most read articles ,other categories are added using admin panel and articles only linked if the category is specified while writing the article (or from database)
What could be the thing in php code that will make ads not appearing in only those 2 categories.Please would you list the probable reasons that conflicts php and javascript etc..or could it be some needed php or apache extension needed to be loaded from the host..

**//Update//** ads are showing up in localhost but not showing on the remote server//
But Please notice that only those 2 dynamic categories are not showing ads; loaded with php like so:

**Popular articles**

```
// Popular articles link
    $popular_li_class = '';
    if ($show_popular)
    {
        $popular_li_class = ' class="selectedcat" ';
    }

    if (_SEOMOD)
    {
        $output = '<li '. $popular_li_class .'><a href="'. _URL .'/articles/popular-01.'. _FEXT .'">'.$lang['articles_mostread'].'</a></li>'. $output;
    }
    else
    {
        $output = '<li '. $popular_li_class .'><a href="'. _URL .'/article.php?show=popular">'.$lang['articles_mostread'].'</a></li>'. $output;
    }
```

and the **latest articles** category:

```
//  wrapper
    $output = '<li><a href="'. _URL .'/article.'. _FEXT .'">'.$lang['articles_latest'].'</a></li>'. $output;

    //  wrapper
    if ($ul_wrapper)
    {
        $output = "<ul id='ul_categories'>\n$output\n</ul>";
    }   
    return $output;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Where is your code, what have you tried? Any screenshots? We need more information!

Comment: You could paste it on pastebin.com and then add a link to it... that would make things easier.

Comment: And which part is not working?

Comment: Your source code does not contain the Adsense code at all. Is it included from another file? Where are your `<script></script>` tags containing javascript? See my updated answer for a simple method of displaying adsense.

Comment: Man i got it !! it's working on localhost !! So what's the extension in php or apache that may do this? tell me all possible extensions to disable on localhost and see if they will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Adsense code is simply javascript code enclosed in `<script></script>` tags. If your php code produces html which contains this code, it is properly loaded on the client's browser, and ads displayed. Check whether your php code contains any errors which prevent output of javascript code. You can check the generated source code.

Displaying adsense code is as simple as writing the following in your php code:

```
include_once("adsense1.php");
```

where adsense1.php contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-";
google_ad_slot = "xxx";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
```

Alternately, you can even do this:

```
<?php

print '<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-";
    google_ad_slot = "xxx";
    google_ad_width = 728;
    google_ad_height = 90;
    //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script>';
?>
```

Comment: In that case, your php code probably contains an error. Difficult to comment without the source code.

Comment: Ads loading on localhost but not working on remote on those 2 pages ... So what's the extension in php or apache that may do this? Please update your answer i updated the question..